# MQTT/PAHO block until clientB has received message from clientA

Tags: mqtt, paho

From what I can tell, [MQTT QOS](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels) is all about Client -> Broker delivery agreements, ie, QOS 1 and 2 can ensure that a published message is received by the broker.

Paho does a good job of blocking based on this basis; `mqttClient.publish` will block until the QOS defined agreement is completed - between the client publishing and the broker.

However, if I have clientA publish a message intended for clientB, how do I block until clientB has received the message from the broker?

eg:

```
ClientB->Subscribe("peer-device/ClientB/application/message")
ClientA->Publish("peer-device/ClientB/application/message")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you don't

Each client has absolutely no idea if any other clients are subscribed to any given topics and this is by design. MQTT is Pub/Sub, not a point-to-point protocol. Part of the point of Pub/Sub architectures is to fully decouple publishers from subscribers

MQTT QOS covers both publisher to broker and broker to subscriber but as 2 distinctly separate steps. The first leg ensures the message reaches the broker (for QOS 1 or 2) and the second leg ensures that the message reaches any subscribers.

Comment: ... so i'd have to write my own blocking mechanism, correct?

Comment: If you want end to end blocking then yes, but I'd be tempted to look for a specific point-to-point protocol rather than force something on top of a decoupled one

Comment: i've implemented my own using a 'commandId' along with the message which is replied to using the same id. for now these seems reliable/efficient enough. thanks.